# PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 confusing

Tags: java

Can anybody tell me what is the use of 128*8 in the code below?
I have written the code for password encryption and I still don't know what this 128*8 is doing.

This is what I get as a return from this code:

67a0759ac6266ca2156555426aae10b18c34b436ea036247e6c0e16cd8d4199b9df508c32cd14e50a533ac00c071888cb8167982d9bf22a89ccd1c02a9d9c76d4e5fb5c3be91711a444a3b453c54790d5b540d7f3d0ef5798cf6a08e5acaf1b0fb445e174befd2e5b97978534aa7c22c4e404503e40f06f6832fe4a5843c9b01

The toHex() function is below: I think returned values are in characters.

```
private static String toHex(byte[] array) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
    {
        BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(1, array);
        String hex = bi.toString(16);
        int paddingLength = (array.length * 2) - hex.length();
        if(paddingLength > 0)
        {
            return String.format("%0"  +paddingLength + "d", 0) + hex;
        }else{
            return hex;
        }
    }



public static String encrypt(String password,String key) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {

       int iterations = 4096;
        char[] chars = password.toCharArray();
        byte[] salt = key.getBytes();

        PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(chars, salt, iterations, 128 * 8);
        SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        byte[] hash = skf.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
        return toHex(hash);
    }
```

Comment: So the length of the returned string is 64 characters?

Comment: (I'd take issue with your choice of names here, too. This isn't encryption, this is secret key generation. I'd also strongly recommend that you never use the parameterless `String.getBytes` method.)

Comment: Ya Its a secret key generation. Can you tell me what is 128*8 and why I am getting 256 bits return value?

Comment: You're not getting 256 *bits* returned. You're getting 256 *characters* returned, each of which encodes 4 bits. So you're getting 1024 bits, which is what you're requesting with 128*8.

Comment: edited the post please have a look

Comment: How come each char encodes to 4 bits? In java char is of 2 byte size.

Comment: Yes, a `char` has 65536 possible values. How many of those different values do you expect in a result which is just hex though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 128*8 is the requested key length, as per the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/PBEKeySpec.html#PBEKeySpec%28char%5B%5D,%20byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29).

> `keyLength` - the to-be-derived key length.

It's not clear that it's in bits, but it is. So you're asking for a key which is 1024 bits long (because 128 * 8 = 1024).

You're getting back a hex representation which is 256 *characters* long, each of which is a hex digit. A single hex digit encodes 4 bits, so you've got a key which is 1024 bits long, just as you asked for.

Comment: I don't know if the returned values are bits or chars. Please have a look at my edited post. Still you think your explanation is right?

Comment: @user3387358: Yes, although that's not how I'd do a hex conversion. How much understanding do you have of what a "bit" is, and how hex works?

Comment: I don't have much understanding of bits and hex. That's the reason I am confused. Do you have any source where I can read about it?

Comment: @user3387358: I'd start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit

Answer (score 0):

The 4th parameter is the key length

```
PBEKeySpec(char[] password, byte[] salt, int iterationCount, int keyLength)
```

Constructor that takes a password, salt, iteration count, and to-be-derived key length for generating PBEKey of variable-key-size PBE ciphers.

Comment: Can you tell me what is 128*8 and why I am getting 256 bits return value?

Comment: see @jon-skeet's explanation below - are you sure the response is 256 bits not 256 characters?